# getting 'error loading layout' while running dash app

Tags: machine-learning, plotly, runtime-error, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am getting 'error loading layout' while running dash app. I have tried all solution also tried unistalling and again installing dash,plotly,pandas libraries but still getting same error.

terminal:

- Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on

  ```
   #code for stock visualization and prediction app
   import dash
   import dash_core_components as dcc
   import dash_html_components as html
   from datetime import datetime as dt
   from datetime import date
   from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
   from flask.helpers import url_for
   import yfinance as yf
   import pandas as pd
   import plotly.graph_objs as go
   import plotly.express as px
   app = dash.Dash()
   server = app.server

   app.layout=html.Div(
       className="container",
       children=[
           #inpot section
           html.Div(children=[
               html.H1("Welcome to stock dash app!",className="start",style={'color':'#ffffff'}),
               html.Div(children=[
                   html.Div(children=[
                       dcc.Input(id="stock_code",type='text',placeholder="Enter Stock Code",className="inputbox"),
                       html.Button('Submit',id='submit_button',className="submit_button",style={'color':'#fffbf5'})
                   ]),
                   html.Div(
                   children=[
                   # Date range picker input
                   dcc.DatePickerRange(
                       id='date_range_picker',
                       min_date_allowed=date(1990,12,31),
                       initial_visible_month=date(2021,12,3),
                       end_date=dt.now, 
                   )
                   ]),
                   html.Div(
                   className='button',
                   children=[
                   # Stock price button
                   html.Button('Stock Price',id='Stock_price_button',className="stock_p_b",style={'color':'#fffbf5'}),
                   html.Button('Forcast',id='Forcast_button',className="forecast_b",style={'color':'#fffbf5'}),

                   ]
                   ),
                   html.Div(children=[
                       dcc.Input(id="days",type='number',placeholder="Number of Days",className="inputbox"),
                       html.Button('Indicator',id='Indicator_button',className="indicator_b",style={'color':'#fffbf5'})
                   ]
                   )
               ])
               ],
                    className='nav'),
           html.Div(
           [

               html.Div(
                   children=[ 
                   html.Img('',id='logo',className='company_logo'),
                   html.H1('',id='c_name',className='company_name',style={'color':'#064635'})
                   ],
                   className="header"),
               html.Div( #Description
                        html.P('',id='description', className='c_desc',style={'color':'#064635'}),),
               html.Div(
                   id='stock_graph'
                   ),
               html.Div(
                   id='indicator_graph'),
               html.Div(
                   id='forcast_graph'
                   )
               ],
           className="content"
       )
       ]
   )
   @app.callback(
       [
           Output('logo','children'),
           Output('c_name','children'),
           Output('description','children')
       ],
       [
          Input('stock_code','value'), 
       ],
       State(component_id='submit_button',component_property='n_clicks')
   )
   def update_data(arg1,arg2):
       ticker = yf.Ticker(arg1)
       inf = ticker.info
       df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(inf, orient="index").T
       img_url=ticker.info['logo_url'],
       name=ticker.info['shortName'],
       des=ticker.info['longBusinessSummary']
       return img_url,name,des


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server(debug=True,)
  ```

Comment: You have to replace `dt.now` to `dt.now()` for the end date.

Comment: error is solved. thank you so much..